# calling ajax function for every Iteration of a foreach loop without any submit button

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

i am pretty new in php/CodeIgniter stuffs so forgive me if my problem feels too silly or noobish to you.

anyway what i was trying to do is to send values to a ajax function & print results for every Iteration of a foreach loop without using any submit button. 
the ajax code is below
`

```
$('#e1').ready(function(){          [ i think this line is wrong ]
  event.preventDefault();

$.ajax({                                                     
    url: "<?php echo base_url('view_cat/u_name');?>",
    type:'POST',
    data: {
    creator: $("#x").val(),
    },
    success:function(data)
    {  
     $(".e2").html(data);
    }
});
});
```

the foreach loop..

```
foreach ($topic as $top){   
  echo "<form action='' id='e1' method='post' class='ee' >
        <input type='hidden' id='x' value=".$top->topic_creator." />;
        </form>"
 echo" <div class='e2'></div>"
```

the controller function..

```
public function u_name(){
    $creator= $_POST['creator'];
    $result1= $this-> view_cat_model-> u_name($creator);
    echo "$result1->username";
}
```

and the model function where 'member' is a different table

```
public function u_name($creator){
     $query2=$this->db->query("SELECT username FROM member WHERE user_id='".$creator."'"); 
     foreach ($query2->result() as $res)
     {
     return $res;
     }
}
```

but the problem here is that, i am getting the same result(the very 1st result) from the ajax function for every foreach iteration!!!

Comment: The first line certainly is wrong, only the `document` has a `ready` handler, regular elements do not.

Comment: Why not to get the data of "e2" inside the foreach loop, it's server side code where you can call server side function and get the data.

Comment: @adeneo Plus, he would need `event` in the function call `function(event)`

Answer (score 0):

Just call the Model/method directly....forget all that ajax.

```
 foreach ($topic as $top){   
    $res = ModelName->u_name($top);
    echo '<div class="e2">' . $res . '</div>';
 }
```

Comment: i know it works but is it permissible to call model directly from view in a mvc structure ?

Comment: Of course it is! You will inevitably have to use model calls directly in a view. An MVC helps you keep things organized and separate for the most part but it's not a rigid theory. Think of this, say you wanted to hide or show a specific menu based on a users type (admin, guest, low level, mid level), so you can create a model class that builds menus based on the user type. How do you suppose you echo that into your view? By calling the model->method() within the view of course.

Comment: With that being said, you could also run the model within the controller (saving the data to a variable) and pass the variable through the views render(); method.

Comment: Ultimately you have to pick and choose when to do what, it's still "your" app. Just be smart about it and don't over complicate things (such as what you had set up here that you asked about).